# Issue with black screen between videos in ExoPlayer

Tags: android, kotlin, exoplayer

I'm using ExoPlayer to play a list of video files, but I'm encountering a problem with a black screen appearing between videos. When one video finishes and the next one starts, there is a brief period of a black screen before the next video is displayed. I have created an instance of ExoPlayer using the following code:

I would like to know how I can resolve this issue and prevent the occurrence of the black screen between videos. Any help or recommendations would be greatly appreciated!

My code:

```
private fun createExoPlayer(context: Context, surfaceHolder: SurfaceHolder): ExoPlayer {
        val bandwidthMeter = DefaultBandwidthMeter.Builder(context)
            .setInitialBitrateEstimate((10500000f / DEFAULT_BANDWIDTH_FRACTION).toLong()).build()
        val loadControl = DefaultLoadControl.Builder()
            .setBufferDurationsMs(3000, 3000, 3000, 3000)
            .build()
        val rendererFactory = DefaultRenderersFactory(context)
        rendererFactory.setExtensionRendererMode(DefaultRenderersFactory.EXTENSION_RENDERER_MODE_OFF)

        val trackSelector = DefaultTrackSelector(
            context, AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(
                30000,
                10000,
                DEFAULT_MIN_DURATION_TO_RETAIN_AFTER_DISCARD_MS,
                DEFAULT_BANDWIDTH_FRACTION,
                DEFAULT_BUFFERED_FRACTION_TO_LIVE_EDGE_FOR_QUALITY_INCREASE,
                Clock.DEFAULT
            )
        )

        val exoPlayer = SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(
            context,
            rendererFactory,
            trackSelector,
            DefaultMediaSourceFactory(context, DefaultExtractorsFactory()),
            loadControl,
            bandwidthMeter,
            DefaultAnalyticsCollector(Clock.DEFAULT)
        ).build()
        exoPlayer.setVideoSurfaceHolder(surfaceHolder)
        exoPlayer.repeatMode = Player.REPEAT_MODE_ALL
        exoPlayer.setForegroundMode(true)
        exoPlayer.volume = 0f
        exoPlayer.setPriorityTaskManager(PriorityTaskManager())

        return exoPlayer
    }


private fun createExternalMediaSource(context: Context): MediaSource {
        val mediaItems = mutableListOf<MediaItem>()
        for (file in externalPlaylist) {
            val mediaUri = Uri.fromFile(file)
            mediaItems.add(MediaItem.fromUri(mediaUri))
        }

        val dataSourceFactory = DefaultDataSource.Factory(context)
        val mediaSourceFactory = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
        val mediaSources = mediaItems.map { mediaSourceFactory.createMediaSource(it) }
        val concatenatingMediaSource = ConcatenatingMediaSource(true)
        concatenatingMediaSource.addMediaSources(mediaSources)

        return concatenatingMediaSource
    }
```

Comment: I have a similar issue: I starts one video but always with a half of second black screen. But if I repeat it indefinetely all next showings are without any black screen. I think it's a rendering problems.  Did you find a solution?